Signature of a metric induced from scalar product space
Suppose I have a scalar product space $\mathbb{R}^n_k$, that is, $\mathbb{R}^n$ equipped with a scalar product $\langle \ , \ \rangle$ such that:
$$\langle x,y \rangle = -\sum^{k}_{i=1} x_iy_i + \sum^{n}_{j=k+1} x_jy_j$$
Now, I want to know what will be the signature of the induced product on the ($n-1$)-dimensional subset of that space restricted by either: $\langle x,x \rangle = r^2$ or $\langle x,x \rangle = -r^2$, for some non-zero $r$. From the examples such as the hyperbolic space, or de Sitter and anti-de Sitter spacetimes, it seems that: for the $r^2$ case, we'll drop one $+$ from the signature; and for the $-r^2$, we'll drop one $-$.
I tried showing this (in the $r^2$ case) by replacing some $x_k$ with an appropriate expression in terms of $r^2$ and other $x_i$ and considering the resulting expression of $\langle x, y \rangle$. Then, I wanted to show that I will still have a $k$-dimensional subspace for which $\langle \ , \ \rangle$ is negative-definite. But this where I stumble, because no matter how I rearrange the terms I can't set appropriate number of terms to 0 and apply something like Cauchy-Schwarz to get what I want.
Should this work and I'm just not doing the algebra right, or has there been some mistake  in the reasoning?

Are you asking about the induced metric on the submanifold ${x;:;\langle x,x\rangle = r^2}$? Or are you also claiming that this set is a subspace (which it most certainly is not)?

@NicholasTodoroff I'm not claiming that. I'm just asking about the metric.

We can define a "pseudogradient" in this space by $\langle v,\nabla f(x)\rangle = D_vf(x)$ where $D_v$ is the directional derivative. Then, just like the usual gradient, $\nabla f$ is orthogonal to the level sets of $f$. This gradient works much like the usual gradient; indeed, $\nabla\langle x,x\rangle  = 2x$ as usual, so $x$ is normal to the tangent space at $x$.
Thus, for $\langle x,x\rangle = +r^2$ you will lose a $+$ in the metric, and for $\langle x,x\rangle = -r^2$ you will lose a $-$ in the metric.
